# Adding a counter to the table

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a counter to the table in the following code. but I couldn't be successful. Can I get a little help, please? thanks. Something like this:

```
$counter = 0;
$counter++;
if($counter % 33 == 0)
```

So that when the counter is added, table will continue after %33 on the right of the page, and it will continue like that, instead of going down the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="etc/sumain.css" />
    </head>

    <body>

<table class="tbresult">

<?php 

include ("confige.php");

$query = 'select * from employees'; 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
if (!$result) { 
    $message = 'ERROR:' . mysqli_error($link); 
    return $message; 
} else { 
    $i = 0; 
    echo '<form name="select" action="" method="GET">';
     echo '<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"  onchange="this.form.submit()">'; 
    while ($i < mysqli_field_count($link)) { 
        $meta =  
        mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i); 
        echo '<option>' . $meta->name . '</option>'; 
        $i = $i + 1; 
    } 
echo '</select>';
echo '</form>';
} 

if(isset($_GET['mySelect'])) {
$myselect = $_GET['mySelect']; 

$sql = "SELECT `$myselect` as mySelect FROM employees";  // add column alias
$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);   

  if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
   {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["mySelect"] . "</td></tr>";

   }

      echo "</table>";


}

} 


mysqli_close($link);

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It looks like you're inserting a value from a get request directly to the mysql query. Isn't it a security threat?

Comment: it can be. For the time being it will only be used on localhost.

Comment: I didn't get what do you want. Do you want to split the table into several ones of no more then 33 rows?

Comment: yes, that's what I tried to do. the table goes down the page to the bottom. I want it to be lined up side by side to the right of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, don't have an HTML form inside a table, this is not valid, AFIK, and can cause you many troubles in different browsers.

You need simply open the table once, then create a counter = 0 and on each while loop add 1 to it. Then check, if it divides by 33 than you close the table and open a new one. After the loop you close the last table.

The side by side alignment can be done with CSS, something like `.tbresult {float: left; width: 200px;}`

Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="etc/sumain.css" />
</head>

<body>

<?php 

include ("confige.php");

$query = 'select * from employees'; 
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query); 
if (!$result) { 
    $message = 'ERROR:' . mysqli_error($link); 
    return $message; 
} else { 
    $i = 0; 
    echo '<form name="select" action="" method="GET">';
    echo '<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"  onchange="this.form.submit()">'; 
    while ($i < mysqli_field_count($link)) { 
        $meta =  
            mysqli_fetch_field_direct($result, $i); 
        echo '<option>' . $meta->name . '</option>'; 
        $i = $i + 1; 
    } 
    echo '</select>';
    echo '</form>';
}

if(isset($_GET['mySelect'])) {
    $myselect = $_GET['mySelect']; 

    $sql = "SELECT `$myselect` as mySelect FROM employees";  // add column alias
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);   

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        // output data of each row
        $table_row_counter = 0;
        echo '<table class="tbresult">';

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            $table_row_counter++;
            if ($table_row_counter % 33 == 0) {
                echo '</table>';
                echo '<table class="tbresult">';
            }
            echo "<tr><td>" . $row["mySelect"] . "</td></tr>";

        }
    }
} 


mysqli_close($link);

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works perfectly!. I will check CSS version, too. thank you again.